# Ric curvature and second fundamental form.

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a minimal submanifod in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, by Gauss equation we have
$$\operatorname{Ric}_M\geq -\|A\|^2$$.

I have done similar calculations for surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. But it seems different, and here codimension is bigger than 1, I am kinda stuck. If anyone is familar with this calculation, could you show me some details?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Oh, I want to prove above inequality. But I have proved it myself after some help. Thanks for your interest.